# Why do text input methods generally omit an undo function?

Tags: keyboard, external-keyboard, input-methods, keyboard-shortcuts, special-chars

I'm reading through my keyboard's resource documentation (I use [MessagEase](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.exideas.mekb) normally), and I see that they state:

[image: MessagEase Screenshot]

> Please note the Android does not provide any **Undo**.

However, I know this isn't actually true — at least, not in any apparent manner — because when using a **physical keyboard** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> invokes `undo` just fine, and doesn't require any additional/external applications, i.e., works natively via generic PNP (I've used telnet, BT, and RF varieties, all of which work).  And yet, mysteriously enough, the function seems to be omitted *intentionally* (disclaimer: I have no evidence to support this conjecture).

In fact, MessagEase has extended input functionalities that include form field controls and ASCII character controls, and yet inputting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> results in a `notdef` glyph output in the exact same form field.

Why is this the case?

EDIT: Please note that I am referring to connecting a physical keyboard to an Android device, I am *not* comparing PC vs Android UX.

Comment: It is possible to implement it with the TextWatcher interface

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question can get better answers from developers than the end user community.

Android framework does have a class named [`UndoManager`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r1/core/java/android/content/UndoManager.java) *"for managing and interacting with the global undo state for a document or application.  This class supports both undo and redo..."*. And Android's `EditText` view (which extends `TextView`, and is commonly used in apps to get text input from the user) does support ***Undo*** and ***Redo*** operations since Android 6 at least. In fact a ROM developer can show these options in long press context menu for every app, as we see ***Copy***, ***Paste*** and ***Select All***, which are displayed [by default](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r1/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#12280). But Undo / Redo always work if the virtual or physical keyboard can send `CTRL-Z` and `CTRL-SHIFT-Z` key events.

I [extended](https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/AnySoftKeyboard/pull/2407/commits) `CTRL-` events support in AnySoftKeyboard for non-terminal apps. So anyone can. Why they don't is purely a matter of choice. There's no technical limitation.

Comment: Note that the `UndoManager` class as of Android 12 is restricted, per: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/non-sdk-12#new-blocked Also based on: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+log/refs/heads/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/content/TextUndoActivity.java it looks like a feature under consideration and paused/dropped/hidden and developers were expected to use [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) to perhaps roll their own undo/redo operations.

Comment: @MorrisonChang hidden APIs are hidden from apps, not from framework. So the non-SDK restrictions don't apply to `EditText`/`TextView`. As of the latest commit, both undo and redo operations are fully handled by these framework classes: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/c39842abd94509113b2d9e5cc904015c3e20cecd/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#11342. But even if Google drops the support (which doesn't seem to be the case so far), extending `EditText` class to handle key events and keeping history won't be a big task.

Comment: I'm not sure which 'developers' you are referring to in your first line vs your last line, 'Android framework developers' or 'third party developers'. I think my point was that the undo/redo functionality in `TextView` isn't clearly spelled out in the official documentation and only hinted at by the XML property [android:allowUndo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:allowUndo). The fact that a third-party app developer needs to look at framework source isn't new but less 'a matter of choice' than 'awareness'.

Comment: @MorrisonChang *"I think my point was that the undo/redo functionality in `TextView` isn't clearly spelled out in the official documentation"*. Yes that's a valid point. And my point is that "*Android does not provide any Undo*" doesn't sound like a valid excuse for not providing such a small feature. It's a matter of app developer's choice, though nothing bad with that.

Comment: Thanks for the information!  Could you elaborate on when you stated "But Undo / Redo always work if the virtual or physical keyboard can send CTRL-Z and CTRL-SHIFT-Z key events."  As I had mentioned in the OP, MessagEase *can* send those inputs, but it only outputs a `notdef` glyph.

Comment: Android's `TextView`/`EditText` handles Undo/Redo events for sure; I provided the links to the source code. *"when using a physical keyboard Ctrl+Z invokes `undo` just fine"*. This definitely means your virtual keyboard is not sending the correct key event. How to send these events: I gave the link in the last paragraph. You can just install ASK keyboard and test it yourself: https://github.com/mirfatif/AnySoftKeyboard